# How to know the free space on system login by ssh command?

Tags: linux, command-line

see i am logged in another system by ssh command Now i want to check how much free space is available on that system then how can i check that? i have just command line interface so is there any command to check that?

Comment: Look at `df` ("disk free?"). Although, there will be more suggestions where this question re-incarnated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df -h`

gives you the **D**isk **F**ree space in **H**uman-readable format.